# Asynchronous behaviour in flask while model does the prediction

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a web app for predicting stock prices using the Flask framework.
There are 3 charts in my web app that I want to display to the user once they enter the input (i.e ticker, start date, end date).

1. closing price chart
2. Box plot
3. prices predicted by my model

while my model predicts the prices of the given stock, I want to display the first two charts to the user as the model takes approximately 30sec to predict the price and I don't want a blank screen during that period of time. Once the prediction has been done by the model, i want to display the third chart to the user.

how can i achieve this in flask? below is my flask code to render the template

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = getdf() #this will get the user input and fetch the corresponding data
        jsonLine, jsonBox = plotGraphs(df)  #this will plot the first 2 charts and return json data of the chart
        train, valid = buildModel(df)  #here model does the prediction and returns the same
        predictionJson = viz.plotPrediction(train, valid)  #this will plot the predictions
        return render_template('chart.html', jsonLine=jsonLine, jsonBox=jsonBox, predictionJson=predictionJson)
    return render_template("chart.html")
```

```
HTML code:

<div id="lineChart" class="chart"></div>
<div id="boxPlot" class="chart2"></div>
<div id="prediction" class="chart2"></div>
```

```
JavaScript code:

<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawPlotlyGraph(graph, id) {
        Plotly.plot(id, graph, {});
    }
    let lineChart = {{ jsonLine | safe}};
    drawPlotlyGraph(lineChart, "lineChart")

    let boxPlot = {{ jsonBox | safe}};
    drawPlotlyGraph(boxPlot, "boxPlot")

    let prediction = {{ predictionJson | safe}};
    drawPlotlyGraph(prediction, "prediction")
</script>
```

Comment: don't solve a problem that shouldn't exist. optimize your prediction cycle.

Comment: Split up your endpoint in dedicated endpoints for the separate functionalities (charts,prediction, etc.)

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing I wanted to see if there are any ways to display them all in one page. if none, then I'll surely go with your approach.